# Prestashop log in from Android

Tags: php, android, authentication, prestashop

I want to create an Android App for our Prestashop eshop. 
What i want is to add functionality to display all the product list, the wish list of a user, and the cart of the user.
For now what I am trying to achieve is to write a log in activity.
Can anybody show me how with php we can log in to Prestashop from an Android device?

My log in code so far is the following but I get an error wrong password. Probably something is wrong with the _COOKIE_KEY_.

```
<?php
// code placeholder
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
include('./config/settings.inc.php');

/**
 * get information from PrestaShop
*/

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('mydomain', 'mykey', false);

$COOKIE_KEY = '4pUiDR9UDX2j475qhnjX6WaI3H6L8FUthMfpIACui1sj1WvMvtnLj5aK';
$email = 'email';
$password = 'password';

$optUser = array(
'resource' => 'customers',
'filter[email]' => '[' . $email . ']',
'display' => '[id,email,lastname,firstname,passwd]'
 );

  $resultUser = ($webService->get($optUser));

  $json = json_encode($resultUser);

  foreach ($resultUser->customers->customer as $info) {
// Prestashop uses the cookie_key in combination with a salt key. To check 
the password use the php function: password_verify();
$salt = substr($info->passwd, strrpos($info->passwd, ':') + 1, 2);
$ZCpassword = md5($COOKIE_KEY . $password) . ':' . $salt;

// Check if password comparison is true or false
if (password_verify($password, $info->passwd) == true) {
    session_start();
    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = 'success';
    $response['message'] = "You did it!";
    setcookie("userId", $info->id);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = 'error';
    $response['message'] = 'Wrong password';
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
 }

  ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morning,

I think you are looking for a rest api or web service, check the prestashop rest api, there you can manage the store with you app calling the server(login, check products etc..)

More info: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+tutorial

Example listing customer you can find it on the url but i will past the example code

```
try {
// creating web service access
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('http://example.com/', 'ZR92FNY5UFRERNI3O9Z5QDHWKTP3YIIT', false);

// call to retrieve all customers
$xml = $webService->get(array('resource' => 'customers'));}catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
// Shows a message related to the error
echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!!! I really appreciate it. I have enabled the WebService and have successfully access it. The only thing is that I do not know how the log in code should look like. Could you please show me how the php log in code should look like?